# Pandoc md to pdf using yaml as settings file

Tags: pdf, pandoc, markdown

I use pandoc to print my booknotes (written in markdown, saved as *{filename}.md*) into **PDFs** for my editor to read and comment. I've created a **YAML** frontmatter file with all my variables.

The variable I can't seem to figure out is how to set the **PDF** output filename. I'd like it to be in the format: *filename_YYYYMMDD_HHMM.pdf*.

Here's my basic yaml code (*booknotes.yaml*):

```
---
documentclass: article
fontfamily: libertine
fontenc: T1
pagestyle: headings
papersize: letter
standalone: true
output:
  pdf:
    pdf-engine: pdflatex
    output: $filename_{date_time}.pdf << what should this be written as?
    from: markdown
...
```

And here's a sample markdown (*notes.md*):

```
---
title: notes
     tags: tag1, tag2, tag3
     keywords: keyword1, keyword2
---

# Lorem Ipsum

>_"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."_

>"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."

---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque imperdiet, urna eget rutrum dignissim, dui sem malesuada lorem, ac consequat enim dui eu mi. In faucibus fringilla tempor. Curabitur molestie nibh eu ipsum rhoncus posuere. Nulla fringilla, velit sit amet egestas aliquam, mauris lacus eleifend massa, vel convallis ipsum quam non lorem. Integer suscipit odio eu nisi porta efficitur. Nam ut scelerisque felis. Ut facilisis posuere massa maximus consequat. In aliquet semper nisl vel faucibus. Cras suscipit mattis turpis, id egestas erat laoreet sit amet.
```

When I try to generate the **PDF** using: `pandoc booknotes.yaml notes.md` , I get on-screen output in what appears to be **HTML**.

I'm using pandoc version: 3.1.1.

Thanks in advance.